# Determinant inequality for trace class operator

Tags: functional-analysis, determinant, trace

Let $A$ be a trace class operator on a Hilbert space. I wonder if there is an estimate of the form
$$
   |\log \det (I + A)| \le C\|A\|_1,
$$
for some constant $C$, where the norm on the right is the trace norm?

If there is a short proof I'm of course interested in it, otherwise a reference would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For general $A$, it is not true even in finite dimension in the $1\times1$ case: because that would imply the inequality $|\log(1+t)|\leq C|t|$, and we can take $t=-1+\varepsilon$ to get the (false) inequality $|\log\varepsilon|\leq C|1-\varepsilon|$ for all $\varepsilon>0$.

For $A$ positive, though, if the eigenvalue sequence of $A$ is $\{\lambda_j\}$, with $\lambda_j\geq0$ for all $j$,
$$
|\log\det(I+A)|=\sum_j\log(1+\lambda_j)\leq\sum_j\lambda_j=\|A\|_1.
$$

If you know that $\|A\|<\delta<1$, then (using Plemelj's formula)
$$
|\log\det(I+A)|=\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{\mbox{Tr}(A^n)}n\right|\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{|\mbox{Tr}(A^n)|}n
\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\|A\|_1\,\|A\|^{n-1}}n\\
\leq\|A\|_1\,\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\delta^{n-1}}n=\left(-\frac1\delta\,\log(1-\delta)\right)\,\|A\|_1.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't have a positive operator, however, I have a family of operators $A(\lambda )$ where $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. I also happen to have $\| A (\lambda ) \|_1\le |\lambda |$ and I'm only interested in the inequality for $|\lambda |$ small.

Comment: In that case you know that $\|A\|<1$. See the edit.

Comment: You are welcome!